# When running postfix & dovecot, who should own /var/mail and what permissions should it have?

Tags: postfix, centos6, dovecot

I had an issue where either postfix or dovecot did not have permission to create user directories in /var/mail.

Doing ls -l '/var/mail' showed me that the owner and group was root root.

```
1 root root 10 May 27 13:48 /var/mail -> spool/mail
```

I tried changing owner and group to postfix, and then dovecot, and both times when I did a ls -l the owner and group remained as root. (this is while logged in as root).

Somebody recommended the chmod needed to be 644, so I changed it to that, and still, the server wouldn't create the user directories in the mail folders.

In the meantime, I changed chmod to 777 and everything started working, but now I have a big security concern.

Why didn't the owner and group change from root when I told it to?

Who should own /var/mail? and what chmod does it need?

Comment: On my Ubuntu 12.04 server `/var/mail/` is owned by `root mail` and permissions are `775`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Who should own /var/mail? and what chmod does it need?

it would depend on postfix/dovecot settings. I'm using special user virtual

```
# groupadd -g 1981 virtual 
# useradd -g virtual -s /sbin/nologin -u 1981 virtual

# chown virtual:virtual /var/spool/mail/
# chmod 750 /var/spool/mail/
```

And then use the user in postfix

```
virtual_gid_maps = static:1981
virtual_uid_maps = static:1981
```

and Dovecot

```
first_valid_gid = 1981
last_valid_gid = 1981
```

Comment: From my point of view usualy both `postfix` and `dovecot` manage the same folder and therefore it is good that they use same user! If each would use a different user eg. `postfix` may not be able to manage files that `dovecot` created and vice versa. In other words, `/var/spool/mail` would be a mess. It is also good to set a "SGID bit" for that folder if it is not set by default.